# Repeating last function call with dot

Tags: vim

I wrote a small function and added a map to jump to the next line that does not match the two first chars in the current line:

```
function! JumpToNextNonMatching()
  let curr_line = getline('.')
  let spattern = '^[^' . curr_line[0] . '][^' . curr_line[1] . ']'
  call search(spattern)
endfunction
nnoremap ,n :<C-U>call JumpToNextNonMatching()<CR><C-L>
```

so if I hit `,n` it will jump to next line that doesn't match the criteria. I would like to use the repeat.vim plugin to use `.` to repeat this operation, i.e., jump to the next line that doesn't match the criteria.

How can I do this with the plugin mentioned or are there better alternatives that I can use?

Comment: To `.` command repeats the last change. Having it repeat a motion is rather confusing experience. Maybe it would be better to have your function set the pattern register, `@/`. Then you just hit `n`.

Comment: read repeat.vim, there are example how to repeat mapped function calls. https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat/blob/master/autoload/repeat.vim

Comment: @PeterRincker he doesn't (my understanding) want to use the `/ n N` mechanism. the function call do `search` every time, the `spattern` would be different. let's say, we have 4 lines `line1:aaa, line2:bbb, line3:aaa, line4:bbb`. Assume the cursor at the first line, if he called his function 3 times, the cursor would jump: `2-3-4`, but if he saved something like `@/`, the jump sequence would be `2-4`

Comment: @Kent you are correct. It looks like repeat.vim could be used here. However I still feel as if the `.` command should do a change. I also do not think `,n` is too much to type vs `.`.

Answer (score 2):

You should have told us what exactly you're struggling with. Using repeat.vim doesn't require many changes:

1. You need to introduce an intermediate `<Plug>` mapping for repeat to invoke.
2. You need to register your mapping with the plugin at the end of your command's execution.

Here you are:

```
function! JumpToNextNonMatching()
    let curr_line = getline('.')
    let spattern = '^[^' . curr_line[0] . '][^' . curr_line[1] . ']'
    call search(spattern)

    silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>JumpToNextNonMatching")
endfunction
nnoremap <Plug>JumpToNextNonMatching :<C-U>call JumpToNextNonMatching()<CR><C-L>
nmap ,n <Plug>JumpToNextNonMatching
```